# Sync Framework - One table in different Scopes

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to use one table in different scopes with different number of columns? Means that, in scope1, [table A] contains all the columns and in scope2 ,some columns are removed from [table A].
Also need to mention that scope1 and scope2 are in 2 seperate applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should be possible. easiest will be to provision your scopes on different schemas so you have completely different Sync Fx objects for each scope.

you will have to take into consideration if columns does not allow nulls (i.e., a column does not allow nulls and is omitted from a scope, the insert or update will fail for that row)

Comment: thanks JuneT, you mean , column omitted from scope but, set default value to '' & Untick allow null in table design,still insert/update will fail?

Comment: Even I create objects in different Schemas, will the _selectchanges stored procedure be a problem? since there is only 1 _selectchanges for a table regardless the schema.

Comment: I have tried using a different Schema, but gives below error. "Expected column '<REMOVED COLUMN NAME>' was not found on the DataTable to be applied to the destination table 'common_employee'.
Parameter name: dataTable". How can I solve this?